# correct way to write a Sum query

Tags: mysql, sum

I'm trying to find out if the code below is in the right format to retrieve the yearly sum of payments

```
select sum(payment)
select mem_type.mtype, member.name, payment.payment_amt
from mem_type, member, payment
where mem_type.mtype = member.mtype
and member.mem_id = payment.mem_id
group by mem_id
having payment.date > '2014-1-1' <'2014-12-31';
```

Comment: Your going to return a dataset, check your from statement as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few problems with the statement.

The keyword SELECT appears twice, and that's not valid the way you have it. (A SELECT keyword is needed in a subquery or an inline view, but otherwise, it's not valid to repeat the keyword SELECT.

The predicate in the HAVING clause isn't quite right. (MySQL may accept that as valid syntax, but it's not doing what you are wanting to do. To return rows that have a `payment.date` in a specific year, we'd typically specify that as predicates in the WHERE clause:

```
 WHERE payment.date >= '2014-01-01' 
   AND payment.date <  '2015-01-01'
```

Also, I'd recommend you ditch the old-school comma syntax for the join operation, and use the JOIN keyword instead, and relocate the join predicates from the WHERE clause to an `ON` clause. For example:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM member 
  JOIN mem_type
    ON mem_type.mtype  = member.mtype
  JOIN payment
    ON payment.mem_id = member.mem_id
```

It's good to see that you've qualified all the column references.

Unfortunately, it's not possible to recommend the syntax that will return the resultset you are looking for. There are too many unknowns, we'd just be guessing. An example of the result you are wanting returned, from what data, that would go a long ways towards a specification.

---

If I had to take a blind "guess" at a query that would meet the ambiguous specification, without any knowledge of the tables, columns, datatypes, et al. my guess would be something like this:

```
SELECT m.mem_id
     , t.mtype
     , m.name
     , IFNULL(SUM(p.payment_amt),0) AS total_payments_2014
  FROM member m
  LEFT
  JOIN mem_type t
    ON t.mtype  = m.mtype
  LEFT
  JOIN payment p
    ON p.mem_id = m.mem_id
 WHERE p.date >= '2014-01-01'
   AND p.date <  '2014-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
 GROUP BY m.mem_id
```

This only serves as an example. This is premised on a whole lot of information that isn't provided (e.g. what is the datatype of the `date` column in the payment table? Do we want to exclude payments with dates of 1/1 or 12/31? Is the `mem_id` column unique in member table? Is `mtype` column unique in the `mem_type` table, can `mem_type` column in the members table be NULL, do we want all rows from the members table returned, or only those that had a payment in 2014, etc. Can the `mem_id` column on the payment table be NULL, are there rows in `payment` that we want included but which aren't related to a member? et al.

Comment: I am trying to show all the monies paid by each member over a one year period, I must mention that I'm a newbie when it comes to MySql, I Have just begun Understanding how queries work, so excuse me if I appear to be leaving out needed information

Comment: @bigaone22: I've provided an example query in my answer. This is just an example, based on some "guesses". It's not guaranteed to "work" for you, but it does give you an example of how we might go about returning total payments for a member, for a given year.

Comment: Thanks very Much @spencer7593: I will give this one a try on my lunch break and let you know if it worked for me

Comment: Just tried it and it worked, just had to do a bit of tweaking of the table names and columns. great stuff @spencer7593 #yourock